# Ubuntu MAAS 2.0 on 16.04 server won't import images

Tags: server, maas

Has anyone seen this error before?

```
ubuntu-maas2 maas.import-images: [WARNING] Finished importing boot images, the region does not have any boot images available.
```

I can't seem to be able to import any images. It appears to be the only warning/error in the maas log file.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I created a local mirror and it appears to be working.

Apache2 + this http://maas.io/docs/en/installconfig-images-mirror